# Use cin.clear() or cin,ignore() for ONLY previous line input?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use cin.clear() or cin,ignore() for ONLY the previous line of input without clearing ALL previous input? For example in my code I prompt the user for input for each month, well if the input is less than 0 I would like the program to clear that negative input so that it does not get total into my calculation. Problem is it clears ALL previous input which still screws up the calculation. Thanks for any ideas in advance.

```
// prompt user for input, keep a total sum of data entered
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter total rainfall for " << year[i] << endl;
        cin >> month[i];
        total += month[i];

    while(month[i] < 0)
    {
        cout << "Ony enter positive numeric values!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
            cin >> month[i];

    }   


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
unsigned int month[12];

for(size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter total rainfall for month " << i+1 << endl;
    while (!(cin >> month[i]))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, try again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    
    }
    // you probably want to repeat ignore() stuff here
    // so in case user inputs something like 10x, the "x" that was left
    // in the stream gets discarded
}
```

Note the array of unsigned integers. This way input like "-5" is automatically considered invalid so you don't need the less than 0 check. Clearing the entire stream shuouldn't worry you - if the input operation succeeds, the relevant part is already stored in your array.

Comment: when I use 'while(!(cin >> month[i]))' the program ends up allowing user to input 2 values for rainfall rather just 1. I have tried it numerous times to no avail.

Comment: @Gmenfan83 Then you're doing something wrong. There should be only 1 `cin <<` statement inside the for loop.

Comment: I see. I think since I have 2, the first being my original prompt then the next inside the while loop its reading the input twice. I will remove the original one.

Comment: That was my problem. I thought the cin>> inside the while loop condition was ONLY READ as a condition and not actual input. Hence the program accepting 2 values since i had 2 cin>> statements. Thanks so much for the tips and help. Everything works as desired!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing up two distinct issues.  `ios_base::clear()`
doesn't remove any input; it resets the error status of the stream.
`istream::ignore( n, ch )`, on the other hand, reads forward until `n`
characters have been extracted or a character `ch` is seen'
`myInput.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' )` should ignore everything up to (and
including) the next `'\n'`.

but your code has one thing that is very strange:

```
cin << month[i];
```

You can't output to `std::cin`.

Comment: Ok I see the distinction between the two. Sorry about that the cin << error I posted, I fixed it. I added it in after copying and pasting my code once i noticed i accidentally omitted it.